# PHP How to generate signature for PayPal Permissions API

Tags: php, api, paypal

We are implementing the PayPal permissions API in PHP, but we got to a point where we can not find how to generate the "signature" for the Auth Header X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION, in order to make calls on behalf of a third party (DIRECT_PAYMENT specifically),

The docs on PayPal state:

> PayPal provides SDKs that you can use to generate authentication header signatures for Java, PHP, and .NET. When you use the SDK, you will get two values, such as the following: 
>   Signature=tLWUfZU9Np/7qgPqWF1LMIWjY1s= 
>   Timestamp=1285744515

But we have checked already the [Permissions SDK](https://github.com/paypal/permissions-sdk-php), and the methods for this are nowhere to be found,

If anyone knows how to generate the signature, or where to find the methods it would be a great help

Thanks

Comment: was you able to do it? if so share the code please.